# Running Coax(RG6) and Cat6 together

Tags: home-networking, cable

I am currently building a house. I am going to network my house meaning that I am going to run a line for phone, internet, and tv to every room. The phone and internet will be cat6 cable and the tv will be RG6. Assuming good quality cable, is it ok to run the RG6 and Cat6 side by side? Well they interfere with each other?

I know that running cat6 next to power will cause interference. I would assume that power would interfere with RG6 as well.

Thanks
Tony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming decent cable, you won't have any trouble.  My house has a very similar arrangement, and I've not had any trouble.

And yeah, keep them both away from power lines.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's ok, just don't run them next to power lines.